# How to move the data that I have called from the Firebase real-time database, in a listview to another activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have a simple listview application. When I click an item, it will send the data to the next activity using Bundle. In the first time, I use this JSON structure

```
"teacher": [
    {
      "name": "Carl",
      "age": "40"
    },
    {
      "name": "Johnson",
      "age": "44"
    }
  ],
```

And this is my Java code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teacher");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                TeacherHelperClass teacherHelperClass = new TeacherHelperClass();
                String name = data.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String age = data.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                teacherHelperClass.setName(name);
                teacherHelperClass.setAge(age);
                arrayList.add(teacherHelperClass);
            }
            teacherAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(teacherAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            Query _query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teacher");
            _query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String _name = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(position)).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String _age = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(position)).child("age").getValue(String.class);

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("dataName", _name);
                    bundle.putString("dataAge", _age);
                    TeacherDetailBottomSheet bottomSheetDialog = new TeacherDetailBottomSheet();
                    bottomSheetDialog.setArguments(bundle);
                    bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

The code works fine. But now I want to change the database to keyed JSON:

```
"teacher": {
    "001": {
      "name": "Carl",
      "age": "40"
    },
    "002": {
      "name": "Johnson",
      "age": "44"
    }
  }
```

And maybe add another child

```
"teacher": {
    "001": {
      "name": "Carl",
      "age": "40",
      "email": "....",
      "phone-number": "...."
    },
    "002": {
      "name": "Johnson",
      "age": "44",
      "email": "....",
      "phone-number": "...."
    }
  }
```

What should I change in the Java code? especially in the setOnItemClick method. I want to show name & age child in the listview, and send all the data (name, age, email, phone) to the next activity. I've searched for the similar question, but haven't found a clear solution.

Comment: Will it be helpful if I write you an answer with pushed keys instead of those 001, 002 keys?

Comment: Yes, it will be helpful. But I think, maybe I need to use the teacher id when I release the app. 001 and 002 is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code should be like:**

**Teacher Model class Should be like below:**

```
Public class TeacherModel{
    String key,name ,age;

 // CREATE empty constructor ,GETTER and SETTER FOR THESE VARIABLES
}
```

**Now, Create a list of TeacherModel class**

```
List<TeacherModel> teachersList = new ArrayList<>();


FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teacher").
addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if(dataSnapshot.exists())
          {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  TeacherModel teacher =           
                              dataSnapshot.getValue(TeacherModel.class);
                            teacher.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                  
                    teachersList.add(teacher);
            }
            teacherAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(teacherAdapter);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And to send Data from one activity to another, you can use shared ViewModel or can make a public class and a variable of that data type and set the value to that variable and access it in another activity;

```
Public class Common{
  Public static List<TeacherModel> teacherList;
}
```

and in onClickListener you can set value to teacherList like `Common.teacherList = teacherList;`

Now in the another activity you can get that list using Common.teacherList;

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.** And, kindly mark this as the correct answer if it helps you.

Comment: Should I create a new file for Common Class? And there's an error in 'List<TeacherModel> teacher = data.getValue(TeacherModel.class);' .... Required type: List .... Provided: TeacherModel

Comment: Sorry my bad, You should just use.   TeacherModel teacher =           
                              dataSnapshot.getValue(TeacherModel.class);       I have edited the añswer above and now it's fine.

Comment: Yes, you need to make a new file for common class, and during development it's quite easier to use that class variables ( above in the code I have made a variable teacherList)  to share data or to store rather than passing by another methods and because it's a public class you can access it and it's variables everywhere needed.

Comment: One last thing, "Now in the another activity you can get that list using Common.teacherList;"... How to get the data? I need to put it in a string. Could you show the code?

Comment: If you want the data which is in the list you can use get() ;                for Example:: Common.teacherList.get(0);                  and if you want to store data of String type and retrieve it in another activity, you can just create another variable of string type for example ...... in Common class make a variable => public static String variableToStoreStringData;        and assign value to this variable Common.variableToStoreStringData="any data you want". now in another activity just use Common.variableToStoreStringData to get the value.

Comment: Welcome bro, Glad to help you.